# Is there a comprehensive recurring Notifications / Tasks app for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applications, software-recommendation

I want to have configurable recurring tasks and notifications for those tasks.

Eg, I need to trim the hedge once a week, but it doesn't matter whenabouts in the week that I do it. So I want a task that recurs once a week, but I also want to set the notifications to remind me twice every day until I mark it as done, the task then being dormant until the following Monday when the reminders will continue twice every day until I have clipped the hedge that week.

I notice that NotifyMe for iPhone does more or less this: does it, specifically, allow me to customize when I am reminded?

Comment: I dont know how you would go about this or an app that does, but if there is something I need to do I will set a reminder in reminders for when I get home, that way if I haven't checked it complete it alerts me again when I arrive at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Due](http://www.dueapp.com) provides most of what I'm looking for.

The developer explains in his FAQ that Apple places restrictions on the number of notifications allowed and when they can repeat. However, the app includes the ability to repeat reminders as well as to "snooze" and/or "postpone" them when they sound.

Answer (score 0):

[Remember the milk](http://rememberthemilk.com) is a popular one. They can do weekly reminders (set for last day of week) and after a week (due 7 days after you complete it).

Comment: That seems to be the recurring task taken care of, but what about the notification / reminder frequency? Ie I want it to remind me every 6 hours until the job is done?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [**Recurring Tasks**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/recurring-tasks/id492584082?mt=8)

> Do you have trouble keeping track of all the things you have to do? 
>   Do you wish someone reminded you when it's time to change the sheets, make a dentist appointment or renew your subscriptions?
>
> If so, this Recurring Tasks (RT) app might be just the thing for you! RT helps you keep track of when you did what last and reminds you when you should be doing it again.